# Consulta mysql llamando al último dato de las últimas 4 fechas - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool Stack trace: #0{main

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer un grafico llamando datos de las últimas cuatro fechas pero agarrando solo el último dato que hay en esas fechas.
Amplio la petición: supongamos que tengo estas fechas con datos

2021-12-18 CAUDAL=40

2021-12-18 CAUDAL=40 (Preciso esté solo y no los anteriores)

2021-12-19 CAUDAL= 50

2021-12-19 CAUDAL=60 (Preciso esté solo y no los anteriores)

2021-12-20 CAUDAL=40

2021-12-20 CAUDAL=40 (Preciso esté solo y no los anteriores)

2021-12-21 CAUDAL=20 (Preciso esté solo y no los anteriores)

SI yo uso esta forma de hacer la consulta en el código, mi web se ve en la imagen siguente:

```
   $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","prueba");
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM systems WHERE DATE(fecha)> CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY");
$querys = $con->query($sql); // Ejecutar la consulta SQL
$data = array(); // Array donde vamos a guardar los datos
while($r = $querys->fetch_object()){ // Recorrer los resultados de Ejecutar la consulta SQL
    $data[]=$r; // Guardar los resultados en la variable $data
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Entonces el grafico muestra más veces la del dia 18 y yo quiero que muestre solo el ultimo dato de esa fecha al igual que en las demás.
Y además necesito que esa consulta la haga como un WHERE username=$user_check. O sea para seleccionar una fila especifica en donde está el usuario donde está iniciada le sesión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si yo hago un

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM systems WHERE DATE(fecha)> CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY WHERE username='$user_check' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Me da este error:

```
   Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\caudalimetro.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\caudalimetro.php on line 7
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta incorporando la estructura de la tabla para que podamos ayudarte. Si además añades unos datos de muestra y qué resultado esperas, mejor aún

Comment: @Excorpion el error ese que subí

Comment: @Excorpion me señala el WHERE del username

Comment: @Excorpion ya subí la foto pa

Comment: Tienes dos `WHERE` en esa consulta, remplaza el segundo por `AND` y ya se va a ejecutar correctamente, aunque no estoy seguro que devuelva los datos como los quieres.

Comment: Tienes que leer el error y entenderlo, dice que la clausula WHERE ya fue analizada anteriormente, significa que la tienes 2 veces.

Answer (score 1):

El error lo estás recibiendo por que la consulta que lanzas es errónea. Al lanzar una consulta errónea en la variable $querys se almacena un **false**, y  al no ser un objeto no se puede llamar al método **fetch_object()** ya que **false** no tiene ningún método.

Concretamente el fallo que tienes en la consulta es que has puesto dos cláusulas WHERE de forma incorrecta:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    systems
WHERE
    DATE(fecha) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
WHERE
    username = '$user_check'
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Si quieres poner dos cláusulas WHERE tienes que sustituir el segundo WHERE y posteriores por 'AND'. La siguiente manera sería la forma correcta de poner tu sentencia:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    systems
WHERE
    DATE(fecha) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY
AND 
    username = '$user_check'
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Una recomendación que te doy, que es el método que uso yo cuando programo, es probar siempre las consultas SQL en un cliente MYSQL como por ejemplo PHPMyAdmin y sólo cuando compruebo que funcionan las copio y las paso al código sustituyendo lo que necesite por variables.

Comment: Hola amigo, probé de esa forma y me muestra un solo grafico de la ultima fecha solamente

Comment: Hola Octavio estoy escribiendo la respuesta con la consulta que necesitas y su explicación. Vuelve a mirar en un rato ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias genio!!

Answer (score 0):

Añado además la consulta que necesitas con la explicación de cómo enfrentarte a este tipo de consultas en un futuro.

Lo que necesitas (si te he entendido bien) es sacar el último caudal de cada fecha. y quedarte solo con un registro de caudal por fecha.

Para ello, y suponiendo que tenemos estos datos:

```
ID  |  FECHA        |  CAUDAL
====|===============|========
1   |  2021-12-18   |  40
2   |  2021-12-18   |  50
3   |  2021-12-18   |  40
4   |  2021-12-18   |  50
5   |  2021-12-19   |  50
6   |  2021-12-19   |  60
7   |  2021-12-19   |  50
8   |  2021-12-19   |  60
9   |  2021-12-20   |  40
10  |  2021-12-20   |  45
11  |  2021-12-20   |  40
12  |  2021-12-20   |  45
13  |  2021-12-21   |  20
14  |  2021-12-21   |  20
```

necesitarías sacar los caudales de los registros con los siguientes ID's :

```
4
8
12
14
```

Para ello necesitarías lanzar una consulta con el operador IN de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    systems
WHERE
    id IN (4,8,12,14);
```

Lo que dice esta consulta es que saque los caudales de todos los registros que su ID esté en el grupo de esos 4 números.

Pero obviamente, estos números que están dentro del IN tenemos que sacarlos de forma automática, ¿y cómo los sacamos? Pues sustituimos el grupo de números que hay dentro del paréntesis por una consulta que nos saque esos números y cualesquiera que necesitemos en un futuro.

La consulta en cuestión es esta:

```
SELECT
    max(id) AS Maxid
FROM
    systems
GROUP BY
    fecha
```

Esta consulta, hace lo siguiente: Agrupa todas las fechas para que muestre solo el ID mas alto (el ultimo) de cada fecha. Si lanzas esta consulta en tu cliente sql podrás comprobar que el resultado son los 4 ID's que necesitabamos.

Por último, solo nos quedaría susituir los 4 numeros que pusimos en la primera consulta por esta subconsulta. Quedando finalmente la consulta completa de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    systems
WHERE
    id IN(
        SELECT
            max(id) AS Maxid FROM systems
        GROUP BY
            fecha);
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Los he separado ya que uno explicaba una pregunta de las dos que hace y la otra respuesta es referente a la otra pregunta. Son dos respuestas diferentes a dos preguntas diferentes que hace en una misma pregunta. Aprovecho para preguntar ya que aunque llevo mucho tiempo registrado, he empezado esta semana a colaborar con respuestas: Por que hay respuestas que se dan como comentarios?

Comment: Hola dryant me da este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\caudalimetro.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\caudalimetro.php on line 7. Y en el caso que quiera poner lo de username='$user_check', como haría?

Comment: El error es por que en la consulta hay algun error. La consulta que te he mandado funciona correctamente en una base de datos que he creado yo para hacer las pruebas, pero en tu base de datos puede haber algun campo con nombre diferente.
Haz como te he comentado antes. Prueba primero la consulta en un cliente SQL, y cuando te funcione la consulta en el cliente SQL entonces copia y pega y cambia los valores por las variables.

Comment: No lo consigo, es demasiado para mi ;(